# Plotting a 3D surface in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I have a lm of the form `lm(log(z) ~ x*y)`.

I can make a 3D scatterplot of the data using `s3d <- scatterplot3d(x,y,log(z))`.

How do I plot the surface of my regression function?

I know I can do `s3d$plane3d(lm(log(z) ~ x + y)` for a simple linear model, but this doesn't work for nonplanar surfaces; e.g. `s3d$plane3d(lm(log(z) ~ x * y)` won't work.

Comment: Have a look at `surface3d()` in the `rgl` package.

Comment: The help page for `scatterplot3d` suggests that you look at `persp`.

Answer (score 3):

So first, you are much more likely to get help if you provide a sample dataset (or your actual data, which would be better) and a reproducible example of your code. Otherwise you are forcing us to do it - which I think is why your question was ignored for 6 hours. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more details.

Second, using `lm(...)` like that, with `formula=log(z)~x*y` is an exceptionally bad idea. Linear modeling is based on the assumption that the errors in the response (`log(z)` in your case) are normally distributed with constant variance. If your `z-data` has normally distributed error with constant variance, then `log(z)` certainly will not. This is a classic mistake; the right way to do this is using generalized linear modeling (see the `glm` package, among others), with `family=poisson`.

Finally, to your question. The code below creates a 3D scatter plot overlaid onto a response surface. It uses the `rgl` package, which generates rotatable 3D plots.

Here I've colored the points so that those below the surface are red and those above are green, and added dropline from each point to the surface.

The tricky bit is that in `surface3d(...)`, the x and y arguments are vectors corresponding to a grid, and z is a matrix with one row for every x value and one column for every y value.

For your real data you may need to tweak the `scale=...` argument in `open3d(...)`.

```
# create sample dataset - you have this already,,,
set.seed(1)   # for reproducible example
df <- data.frame(x=sample(1:50,50)/50,y=sample(1:50,50)/50)
df$z <- with(df,exp(4*x + 2*y - 6*x*y + 6)+rnorm(50,sd=500))
fit <- lm(log(z) ~ x*y,df)   # bad, bad, bad - don't do this!!!

# you start here...
df$pred <- predict(fit)
# set up matrix of z-values
x <- seq(min(df$x),max(df$x),len=100)
y <- seq(min(df$y),max(df$y),len=100)
plot.df <- expand.grid(x=x,y=y)
plot.df$z <- predict(fit,newdata=plot.df)
library(reshape2)
z <- dcast(plot.df,x~y,value.var="z")[-1]

# plot the points, the fitted surface, and droplines
library(rgl)
colors <- 2.5+0.5*sign(residuals(fit))
open3d(scale=c(1,1,0.2))
points3d(df$x,df$y,log(df$z),col=colors)
surface3d(x,y,as.matrix(z),col="blue",alpha=.2)
apply(df,1,function(row)lines3d(rep(row[1],2),rep(row[2],2),c(log(row[3]),row[4]),col=colors))
axes3d()
title3d(xlab="X",ylab="Y",zlab="log(Z)")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. I'm trying to take your advice using glms, but I'm running into problems. Whereas lm(log(z) ~ x*y) works fine, glm(z ~ x*y, family=poisson) gives me errors: e.g. "In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 0.000005". Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you upload your data somewhere (Dropbox?) and post a link to it in your question?